# dial tcp : socket: too many open files

Tags: go

I'm getting dial tcp : socket: too many open files error when i do load test.By setting ulimit its working fine but is there any other solution without setting ulimit?

Code:

```
package main
import (
 "fmt"
 "io"
 "io/ioutil"
 "encoding/json"
 "net/http"
 )

type Struct_Response struct {
    Meta struct {
        Requestid        string
    }
} 

var HttpClient = &http.Client{}

func main(){
    apiUrl := "http://example.com"
    JsonStr :="teststr"
    conn_token :="1233333333333"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", apiUrl, bytes.NewBuffer(JsonStr))
    if err!=nil{ 
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("requestid", "1234")
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer "+conn_token)
    req.Header.Set("Connection", "close")

    resp, err := HttpClient.Do(req)
    req.Close=true
    if resp!=nil && resp.StatusCode==200 {
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        var Responce Struct_Response
        err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(string(body)), &Responce)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)
        resp.Body.Close()
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there's not. If you're hitting the open file descriptor limit, the only way around that is to increase the limit.

Comment: @hobbs can u suggest me the best way to restrict fewer sockets ?

Comment: From the error, it sounds like your process, or in the OS in general (linux?)- too many sockets are opened.. You can verify that by looking into `ls /proc/$pid/fd`..

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may be that you're not cleanly closing connections which causes delays to be added before reusing TCP port client port numbers.

In your code example above, the response body is only consumed and closed when the status is 200. You should always consume/close the response body when present.

Comment: if status!=200, then i'm getting resp as nil. so i'm unable to close it

Comment: Try running `netstat -na` and see if you have long output. In particular, look for `TIME_WAIT`, if you have many of those it indicates that there are connections that didn't do a full close handshake. This [TCP states](https://benohead.com/blog/2013/07/21/tcp-about-fin_wait_2-time_wait-and-close_wait/) info page seems to say that many TIME_WAIT means it's in a passive close transition and that it's okay until it affects performance. Seems like you want an active close sequence if possible.